# Is there a way to type this correctly in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, type-constraints

I want to type such function in typescript:

```
(anyClass, somePropertiesObject) => newClassExtendingAnyClassWithPropsAddedFromTheObject
```

The purpose of the function is pretty simple, just take some class and some object as an argument and return new class extending supplied class, but with properties added from the second argument.

I have really hard time figureing out how to type this correctly. I would really appreciate help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://tsplay.dev/WvYknm ? If yes, I can answer

Comment: Please consider adding more context to your question with some example of reproducible code

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```js
type AnyClass = new (...args: any[]) => any

const extend = <
    Class extends AnyClass, Obj extends Record<string, unknown>
>(AnyClass: Class, somePropertiesObject: Obj) => class _ extends AnyClass {
        props = somePropertiesObject

        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(args)
        }

    }

class Derived {
    name = 'Derived'
}
const obj = {
    age: 42
}

const Result = extend(Derived, obj);

const test = new Result()

test.name // string
test.props.age // number
```

`AnyClass` - represents a type of any constructor. I mean any function which can be called with `new` keyword. I have used this constraint in `extend` function since you expect first argument to be a class.

`Obj` - represents any object with `string` key and `unknown` value. Corresponds to second argument.

I have used `props` property in new class to store `somePropertiesObject`.

As you might have noticed, all properties of provided class and object are allowed to use in a result.

Answer (score -1):

We should use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) here:

```
type MergeFunction = <A, B>(objectA: A, objectB: B) => A & B;

const mergeObjects: MergeFunction = (objectA, objectB) => ({ ...objectA, ...objectB });

// Usage:
const result = mergeObjects({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 });
result.a; // 1
result.b; // 2
```

`A` - original object (or class, it looks like this does not matter in this particular case)

`B` - another object we want to megre with

`A & B` - TS type describing an object that contains properties from both `A` and `B`

TypeScript will automatically compute a type of the result (return value).

Comment: Please remember to include explanations when contributing answers.

Comment: @JeremyCaney, ok, thanks for the advice.